# kill python script and see last line executed

Tags: python, debugging, process, stack-trace

I have a python script which works in and endless loop, the script does several things and uses a couple of methods from classes, logs information to a couple of loggers I have and works with SQS Amazon queues. Something like this:

```
A = ClassA()
B = ClassB()
C = ClassC()

while True:
    # pull messages from SQS
    messages = sqs.pull_messages()
    logger.info('Pulled messages from SQS')
    A.do_something(messages)
    logger.info('Doing something on class A')
    # download something from the internet
    data = B.download_something()
    logger.info('Downloaded something')
    C.insert_to_database()
```

The script works fine for several days without running out of memory or exiting the script because a traceback, I start my script like this in my Linux box:

```
python script.py &
```

Days later I can come back to the box and find the script is still running but the logger logged data until 1 day ago, it's not a common pattern, sometimes the script stops working after hours, sometimes after days, but never gets killed.

So my question is, is there a way I call kill the process `kill pid` and see what was happening ? Starting a post mortem debugger will show me what the script was doing, or in which line it was before I killed it ? Is there any approach to take on this ?

Comment: maybe raising some exceptions?

Comment: @gen, I do that, but as I told, the script does not stop running I have to kill it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strace will give you a view of system calls and their responses. It may be lower level than you like, but it can let you see if a network call failed, or a read timed out, or whatever may have happened.

On the standard amazon linux image strace is available with 'yum install strace'

To find a program "mycommand"

```
# find the pid
ps -ef | grep [m]ycommand
# use the pid from the previous command
strace -p $thepid
```

Comment: That is in fact, usefull, it shows that the script is running or if it has stopped somewhere waiting for some kind of input, the only problem is that is, as you said, low level, is there ahy other approach ?

Comment: There are *slightly* higher level tools available. ltrace goes from system calls to the C libraries at least. A slightly different approach would be to attach to the process with gdb, but if you don't already know gdb this would not be the best way to learn it...

Comment: Actually I need to amend that last comment, gdb has a python extension that looks as though it will give you python code. I haven't used it, but it looks great http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to 
redirect the stderr to a file

```
python script.py 2> my_error_file &
```

Python will provide the info which line it was executing
and if the program fails, you can check the file

you will have to kill it with `kill -SIGINT <pid>` though

Comment: thanks, but as I said, the program does not fail, it get stuck somewhere, the process has to be manually killed.

Comment: does not matter, if you kill the process, python will throw an exception and print the stacktrace to stderr

Comment: Well, I tried that, only thing I got on the file is, the normal loggin and a final line saying `[1] Terminated script.py 2> ERROR_FILE &`

Comment: are you sure? works fine for me, did you call it with -SIGINT?

Answer (score 0):

Something should be printed if you manually kill the process, but if not, you can specify what you want to print when you use "ctrl + c" to stop the process

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("...")
  traceback.print_exc()
```